# oracle database 12c problems when modify listener.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, windows64

I have problems when I modify the listener.ora , when I put a new address , as shown .

listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\name\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora

Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =

(SID_LIST =

```
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\name\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\name\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
)
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = OracleDB)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\User\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME = ORCL)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = Oracle8)
  (SID_NAME = ORCL)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = Prova)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\User\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME = ORCL)
)
```

)
LISTENER =

(DESCRIPTION_LIST =

```
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  **(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.10)(PORT = 1521))**
)
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
```

)

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\name\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log

when I do not put the address with asterisk everything works correctly in local, but I need to connect oracle from another client (other PC).
in aid I found places I have to add this:

** (ADDRESS = ( PROTOCOL = TCP ) (HOST = 192.168.0.10 ) (PORT = 1521 ) ) **

but when I put this in the listener.ora nothing works.
errors are as follows:

oracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener 
It does not automatically start.

enter cmd and put lsnrctl star and I get this error:
TNS- 12560 and TNS- 00530

if I make a lsnrctl status I get the error:
TNS- 12535 , TNS - 12500

how can I solve this problem?
to connect from a client (other PC) is correct only make this change in the listerner.ora or some change is needed more ?

Finally is Oracle for Windows x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clarifying a few points: The host of the database runs the listener(s). The listener configuration comes from tnsnames.ora and listener.ora located where you've specified. 'localhost' is obviously the same address as the database host.

In the listener.ora, the IP you are trying to add should be an IP address for the database host. (It's not clear from the post, but just to be clear, the listener does not run on the client.) I personally replace the 'localhost' entry with the database host IP address.

At this point the listener should start correctly and it will be listening for connections on the IP and port specified.

The remaining problems with the client connectivity get a bit more complicated because of network configuration, authentication, client s/w involved, etc. Some of these configurations relate to the sqlnet.ora file (both on the server and the client).

But basically, on the client, you need to configure the connection to connect to the IP address, port, and one of the global_names referenced in the listener.ora (This could be configured via a tnsnames.ora file. There are other client configuration options.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.
I have clarified many doubts.
I have been able to connect.